# Denote $X \prec Y$ if $X$ can be embedded to $Y$. Give an example where $X \prec Y \prec X$, but $X$ is not homeomoprhic to $Y$.

Tags: general-topology

> Denote $X \prec Y$ if $X$ can be embedded to $Y$. Give an example where $$X \prec Y \prec X$$but $X$ is not homeomoprhic to $Y$. Hint: one example can be made from intervals.

The definition for embedding in my book is that if from map $f:X \to Y$ we can get a homeomorphism $f_1:X \to f(X)$, then $f$ is an embedding.

I'm still a bit confused about what it means to embed a space  $X$ to $Y$. Intuitively I would think of this that we could somehow treat $X$ as a subspace of $Y$. For example it would seem that we could embed $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^2$ as $\Bbb R=\Bbb R \times \{0\} \subset \Bbb R^2$?

From the hint it would seem that I could pick $X$ to be some interval say $(0,1)$ and $Y$ to be for example $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$, then I guess that $X \prec Y$, but I don't think that $Y \prec X$ anymore? Also in this example $X$ isn't homeomorphic to $Y$.

Comment: "$X$ can be embedded into $Y$" means $X$ is homeomorphic to  a subspace of $Y$.  E.g. the identity function embeds $X=(0,3)$ into $Y=[0,3]$ and $Y$ is homeomorphic to $[1,2]\subset X$ but $Y$ is compact and $X$ is not compact.

Comment: So $i : X \to Y$ is an embedding of $X$ to $Y$? How can we embed $Y$ to $X$ back?

Comment: Map Y to [1,2]. E.g. f(y)=(1+y)/2.

Answer (score 1):

$X=(0,1)\cup \{2\}, Y=(0,3)$. Note that $Y$ is connected but $X$ is not. $x\to \frac  x 3$ is an embedding of $Y$ in $X$.

Comment: If you want only intervals, as in the OP's hint, use $X=(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ e.g. The same arguments apply.